# Sonar qube i installed is not working and it show "...... Try: Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: testing, sonarqube

This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

● sonarqube.service - SonarQube service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-03-27 16:28:00 EAT; 10min ago
Process: 6180 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start (code=exited, status=0/S>
Main PID: 6210 (java)
Tasks: 104 (limit: 9261)
Memory: 1.3G
CPU: 2min 40.632s
CGroup: /system.slice/sonarqube.service
├─6210 java -Xms8m -Xmx32m --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add->
├─6594 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/>
└─7335 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.enc>

Mar 27 16:28:00 abel-HP-250-G6-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Starting SonarQube service...
Mar 27 16:28:00 abel-HP-250-G6-Notebook-PC sonar.sh[6180]: /usr/bin/java
Mar 27 16:28:00 abel-HP-250-G6-Notebook-PC sonar.sh[6180]: Starting SonarQube...
Mar 27 16:28:00 abel-HP-250-G6-Notebook-PC sonar.sh[6180]: Started SonarQube.
Mar 27 16:28:00 abel-HP-250-G6-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started SonarQube service.
lines 1-18/18 (END)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially the part about the Golden Rule. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78232174/edit) to include a clear description of what you are attempting to do, including the exact commands you have run.  Also include any research you have done on the problem. Have you searched the web for that error message?  What did you find? What did you try? What were the results?

Comment: Also, to make your post readable, please see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](/help/formatting) and the [Markdown help](/editing-help). Thanks!